# Running javascript function on server using Mongo driver without $eval

Tags: mongodb, eval

we have a Ruby server application running on MongoDB.

We need to run function on a server which calculates sizes of objects per customer. We used db.command(:$eval...) for this however that's not deployable to production because such app would require rights to the whole db.

We were investigating to use db.system.js.save() . It is possible to run such a saved function withou using db.command(:$eval...) ?

Or would be other options for this? I'm currently also looking at the possibility to use mapReduce for this.

Thanks in advance, 
Michal

Comment: Do you _need_ to run it in mongod? Why? In absense of real stored procedures, the only sane way is to load some data into the app, calculate, save back.

Comment: Well, this is used for calculating how much storage particular customer uses. Basically every object in our Mongo has something like CustomerId. Customer can, of course, have lot of objects. So the idea is that we don't have to transfer all of them from db server to the app just to calculate their sizes, because that would be lot of data. Also it is quite slow pass the object through the mongo ruby driver pipeline.

Comment: Well, you could calculate faster using aggregation pipeline, but then you return it to the app and app updates the client. Little you can do to have _everything_ in the db, both reading and writing.

Comment: I don't see how can calculate object's size using aggregate().
In the end, I used mapReduce and it works OK and it is quite simple

    MAP = "function() { emit(0, Object.bsonsize(this)) }"
    REDUCE = "function(_, sizes) { return {count: sizes.length, size: Array.sum(sizes)} }"
    res = coll.find({customerId: customerId}).map_reduce(MAP,    REDUCE).first
    # Empty 
    return { count: 0, size: 0 } unless res
    info = res[:value]
    if info.is_a? Numeric  # Mongo does not call reduce function for single    value
       return { count: 1, size: info }
    end
    return info

Comment: Sorry for the formatting